# Dudas sobre aplicación multihilo en C#

Tags: c#, hilos

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en *C#*, donde me conecto a varios relojes checadores mediante la API de *ZKTeco*. Estos están controlados mediante una base de datos, es decir, para diferenciar un reloj checador de otro, cada uno tiene una dirección *IP* diferente. Ya tengo la conexión al dispositivo, también obtengo marcajes en tiempo real en un `Datatable` para ser mostrados y los guardo en la base de datos, pero ahora estoy tratando de que la conexión sea dinámica, he creado un `Datatable` para listar todos los checadores leídos de la base de datos, agregué botones de "Conectar" y "Desconectar", y tengo una función que hace todas las operaciones. Esta recibe como parámetro la *IP* del checador.

**Mi pregunta es:** ¿Cómo puedo crear hilos para cada checador de forma dinámica, basándome en los registros de mi base de datos y que cada uno de ellos use mi función que hace todas la operaciones, de tal manera que pueda conectar los `n` checadores a mi aplicación?

**Ejemplo:** En la base de datos tengo 5 checadores, se crearían 5 hilos y usarían la función `operaciones(String ip)`, obteniendo los marcajes como ya los tengo hasta este momento.

Leí algo referente a `BackGroundWorker` pero no logro comprender cómo se utilizaría para estos fines.

A continuación muestro el código, nuevamente gracias:

**Datatable donde se realizan las conexiones**

En este método se muestran las *IP* de los dispositivos y los botones para hacer las conexiones a los relojes checadores. En este punto es donde crearía los hilos (procesos) para cada *IP*.

```
private void dtConexiones_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int currentRow = int.Parse(e.RowIndex.ToString());//Obtiene la fila actual
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && this.dtConexiones.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "conectar" && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        dtConexiones[0, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dtConexiones[1, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dtConexiones[2, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dtConexiones[3, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dtConexiones[4, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

        MessageBox.Show("Conectandose al dispositivo: " + Convert.ToString(dtConexiones[4, currentRow].Value) + " del BIC: "+ Convert.ToString(dtConexiones[3, currentRow].Value), "Obteniendo IP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        //Despues de seleccionar el boton de conectar en la tabla, se crea el proceso con la ip que se obtiene de la tabla.
        ipdispositivo = Convert.ToString(dtConexiones[4, currentRow].Value);

    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && this.dtConexiones.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "desconectar" && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        bandera = false;
        dtConexiones[0, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dtConexiones[1, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dtConexiones[2, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dtConexiones[3, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dtConexiones[4, currentRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

        MessageBox.Show("Desconectandose al dispositivo: " + Convert.ToString(dtConexiones[4, currentRow].Value) + " del BIC: " + Convert.ToString(dtConexiones[3, currentRow].Value), "Obteniendo IP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar los threads de forma dinámica debes recorrer la lista de registos y en cada iteración utilizar la clase ThreadPool que sirve para manejar una lista de threads:

```
foreach(DataRow row in datatable.rows) {
    Object ip = row["ip"];
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(operaciones), ip);
}
private void operaciones(Object ip)
{
    String ip = ip as String;
}
```

WaitCallback es el objeto que será llamado por el ThreadPool y una vez que este sea llamado ejecutara la función que recibió como parámetro en su constructor, en este caso la función operaciones, nota que pasé como Object la ip porque el método que se pasa a WaitCallback solo debe aceptar parámetros de tipo Object.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder me ha sido de mucha ayuda el código que me proporcionaste, me surgió la siguiente duda, de que manera puedo ejecutar cada 3 segundos el método 'operaciones' que se ha creado con los hilos de tal manera que pueda refrescar la información que va llegando de los relojes checadores, saludos y nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es: en vez de llamar a Operaciones llamar un método que solo me sirva para crear un timer y que este timer llame al método operaciones


foreach(DataRow row in datatable.rows) {
    Object ip = row["ip"];
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(operaciones), ip);
}
private void crearTimer()
{}
private void operaciones(Object ip)
{
    String ip = ip as String;
}

static Timer _timer;        
 _timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
_timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it

Comment: Muchas gracias he entendido muy bien lo que me comentaste y me ha servido, te agradezco nuevamente, he probado el código y realmente funciona, pero ahora, al conectar dos dispositivos, por ende debe de crear dos hilos, los crea, solo que toma al dispositivo 1 y después al dispositivo 2, quedándose trabajando con el dispositivo 2, mi pregunta es: ¿Hay una forma de intercambiar la ejecución de cada hilo? y de esta manera hacer que los dispositivos usen el método de operaciones(String ip)? Espero haberme explicado. Saludos hasta Honduras, nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Cuando se crean los dos threads deberian de seguir funcionando el Primero con el Primer dispositivo y el Segundo Thread con el Segundo dispositivo respectivamente, explicame un poco mejor lo de intercambiar la ejecucion de los hilos que quieres lograr, saludos hasta Mexico tambien.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente @David cuando creo los hilos mediante este código: ipdispositivo = Convert.ToString(dtConexiones[4, currentRow].Value);
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtConexiones.Rows)
                {
                 Object ip = ipdispositivo;
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(operaciones), ip);
                    crearTimer(); }    Me gustaría controlar que hilo se va a ejecutar, por ejemplo, tengo 5 dispositivos, pero solo conecto 2, ¿Como puedo saber que hilo se esta ejecutando ? Espero sea mas claro, gracias y saludos recibidos

Comment: La funcion que debes pasar al Threadpool es directamente la de crearTimer(Object ip); en vez de la de operaciones, ahora dentro de la funcion crear timer se deberia llamar la funcion operaciones para cada uno de los dispositivos void createTimer(Object ip) { static Timer _timer; _timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(operaciones); _timer.Enabled = true; }

Comment: Lo siento el correcto es el siguiente: crear una variable en la clase que sea actual Ip para poderla utilizar en la llamada a operaciones, o directamente desde operaciones string IpActual = ""; createTimer(Object ip) { IpActual = ip as String; static Timer _timer; _timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed); _timer.Enabled = true; } static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
 operaciones(IpActual);
    }

Comment: asi se crea primero un timer para cada uno de los Threads que se crean y este timer esta llamando a su funcion operaciones cada N cantidad de segundos.

Comment: Hola que tal amigo, he hecho las modificaciones y en efecto los hilos son creados de forma dinámica, todo el proceso es correcto, pero me sigue quedando una duda, en la siguiente imagen puedes observar que en la primer ejecución accede al dispositivo 1(hilo 1), pero después pasa al dispositivo 2 (hilo 2), este ultimo es el que se queda ejecutando de forma indeterminada y no cambia al dispositivo 1 (hilo 1): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44qibjqiACVeTJFNS01U3EzQ0U/view Hay alguna forma de intercambiar la ejecución de los hilos para ejecutarlos a la par, saludos y gracias de verdad